# How can I to leave NA in upper triangle matrix?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
dt <- data.frame(X=sample(5), Y=sample(5))
dt <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dist(dt)))
```

I would like to replace `NA` with all enteries in `dt`. I know, how loops work, but I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `upper.tri` as in

```
dt[upper.tri(dt, diag=FALSE)] <- NA
```

and change `diag=FALSE` to `diag=TRUE` to include diagonal